# Why doesn't IE8 handle iframe onload events?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, internet-explorer-8

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
function on_iframe_load() {
    document.getElementById('iframe_a').onload = function() {
        alert('Thanks for the visit!');
    };
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe name="iframe_a" id="iframe_a"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="iframe_a" onclick="on_iframe_load();">Go!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

It works in all major browsers with no problem, but IE8 (and probably prior versions) don't understand it.

**Update**: Just came up with a solution, but I'm not sure if it's right coding. Please review:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>
            var clicked = false;

            function activate() {
                clicked = true;
            }

            function pop() {
                if (clicked) {
                    alert('Thanks for the visit!');
                };
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <iframe name="iframe_a" onload="pop();"></iframe>
        <a href="http://www.example.com/" target="iframe_a" onclick="activate();">Go!</a>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean? The alert message should only appear when you click on the link, not on the initial page load.

Comment: I dropped your code straight into JSFiddle.net disabled the libraries. Set IE9 to work in IE8 mode, and your sample works as you want. Is this 'sample' code as oppose to real problem code?( I know ie9 in ie8 mode is not a exact test)

Comment: @Adrian: No, this is the real code that I tried in real IE8, not in an emulator.

Comment: Yep just tried it, if does 'fail' in a real ie8, I can get it to work using onreadystatechanged event...

Comment: I don't think adding flag for "click" is a reliable solution. You'll better try unobtrusive way of coding in javascript (look at my edited answer). Using `attachEvent` for IE and `addEventListener` for other browsers solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Using inline attribute on iframe seems to fix this issue in IE8:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
function onIframeLoad(iframe) {
    if(iframe.src) {
        alert('Thanks for the visit!');
    }
}
function onLinkClick(url) {
    document.getElementById('iframe_a').src = url;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="iframe_a" onload="onIframeLoad(this);"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.example.com/" onclick="onLinkClick(this); return false;">Go!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**update by request:**

You should try writing more unobtrusive javascript. Writing code in such way may prevent you from such strange bugs in IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <iframe id="display-frame"></iframe>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/">Go!</a>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var iframe = document.getElementById('display-frame'),
                link = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

            // load handler
            function onIframeLoad() {
                alert('Thanks for the visit!');
            }

            // event handlers
            if(iframe.addEventListener) iframe.addEventListener('load', onIframeLoad, false);
            else if(iframe.attachEvent) iframe.attachEvent('onload', onIframeLoad);

            link.onclick = function() {
                iframe.src = this.href;
                return false;
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I updated the question with a solution I just came up with. Would you please review my code and let me know what you think?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can't add a load listener to an iFrame in IE using the DOM property once the page has loaded.

But you can use `attachEvent`, so:

```
function on_iframe_load() {
    function foo() {
        alert('Thanks for the visit!');
    };
    var el = document.getElementById('iframe_a');

    if (el.attachEvent) {
      el.attachEvent('onload',foo);
    } else if (el.addEventListener) {
      el.addEventListener('load', 'foo', false);
    }
}
```

I was testing in IE 6 and reversed the usual test order so that `attachEvent` is used in preference to `addEventListener`. You may want to test more recent versions of IE to see if the opposite order works and also test other IE–like browsers such as Opera.

#### Edit

Modified the code after testing (silly me) to use `addEventListener`. Here's something that works in IE and others:

```
function on_iframe_load() {
    function foo() {
        alert('Thanks for the visit!');
    };
    var el = document.getElementById('iframe_a');

    if (el.attachEvent) {
      el.attachEvent('onload',foo);

    } else {
      el.onload = foo;
    }
}
```

And if you use an onload attribute in the markup, you don't need to add the listener using script.

Answer (score 2):

It works :)

tested on IE8, ff, chrome

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframeid');

    if (iframe .attachEvent) {
      iframe .attachEvent('onload',alert("IE Iframe loaded"));

    } else {
      iframe .onload = alert("Other than IE Iframe loaded");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use jquery:

```
$(iframe).bind( 'load', function(){} );
```