# How to make dynamic iFrame height?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to make dynamic iFrame height in order to fit the content of the page.

I have two pages. index.php and example.html

I insert the "example.html" as an iFrame in "index.php", content height in "example.html" is changeable.

This is my code in "index.php"

```
<iframe src="example.html" name="iframe1" id="myiframe" marginwidth="0"
marginheight="0" align="top" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0">
</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
var f = document.getElementById("myiframe");
f.onload = function() {
  this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + "40px";
}
</script>
```

My CSS:

```
#myiframe {
margin: auto;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
height: auto;
min-height: 255px;
height: auto !important;        /* for IE as it does not support min-height */
height: 255px;                   /* for IE as it does not support min-height */
width: 100%;
}
```

The iFrame works fine but the dynamic height doesn't works at all. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Are both pages on the same domain ? Are there any JavaScript security warnings ?

Comment: Yes, They are both hosted online on the same domain and path also. @grimmus

Comment: What browser are you using? iframe onload() support is of varying quality across browsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910534/why-doesnt-ie8-handle-iframe-onload-events for example.

Comment: Actually I tested it on Chrome and Mozilla only @axel_c

Comment: I'd do [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11807287/1169519) within `iframe`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery, it can be done by using $(window).height();

```
<iframe src="example.html" width="100%" class="myIframe">
<p>Hi</p>
</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
$('.myIframe').css('height', $(window).height()+'px');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, place this in the parent page.

```
$('iframe').load(function () {
    $(this).height($(this).contents().height());
    $(this).width($(this).contents().width());
});
```

If they are different subdomains, you'll want to add this to both parent and iframe page:

```
    document.domain = "shareddomain.com"
```