# Panel is not refreshing on IE 8 and IE o

Tags: javascript, java, internet-explorer, wicket

Hi I have a problem the codes does not work on IE8 and IE9 but working with higher version and other browsers like chrome. The page does not reload on IE8 and IE9 only.

Scenario I'm doing when I choose 1 option on the radio button. the panel should reload.

This is my java code.

**ProfileBasePage.java**

```
// Javascript used to resize the Modal page after hiding/showing components.
Public static String POPUP_RELOAD_JS =
"var iFrame = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];"
+ "(iframe.onload)();";

/** Calls the Javascript code to reload the modal panel only when the popup parameter is set to true.*/
protected void reloadPopupiFrame(AjaxRequestTarget target)
{

//POPUP_PARAMETER="popup"

    String popup = getRequest().getRequestParameters().getParameterValue(ProfileBasePage.POPUP_PARAM_KEY).toString();

//TRUESTRING = "true"
    //append the javascript used to reload the modal iFrame.
    if(ProfileBasePage.TRUESTRING.equalsIgnoreCase(popup))
{
target.appendJavaScript(POPUP_RELOAD_JS);
}
}
```

Comment: Is the browser reporting a javascript error? If so, please post it.

Comment: No its not. The code does not work on IE 9 below. But it works with other browsers or edge

Comment: Which wicket version are you using? Is the ajax request actually being executed? Does the response contain your javascript? The code doesn't really tell us much to help you ...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Wicket `ModalWindow` class, you can resize it with Wicket very own JavaScript command:

```
target.appendJavaScript("window.parent.Wicket.Window.current.autoSizeWindow();");
```

Answer (score 0):

`(iframe.onload)()` looks fishy. Maybe older IE versions do not support it.
Better use a proper function call instead. I.e. your iframe should look like: `<iframe onload="myOnLoadOrResizeHandler()"...>` and then the JS code executed by Wicket should be: `target.appendJavaScript("myOnLoadOrResizeHandler();")`.

Comment: This SO question seems to indicate it won't work in IE8 but should work in IE9: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910534/why-doesnt-ie8-handle-iframe-onload-events